# Run mvn install command skipping selected jar

Tags: java, maven, groupdocs

What I need to do is to build a jar without one huuuge dependency, which is a fellow below

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.groupdocs</groupId>
        <artifactId>groupdocs-conversion</artifactId>
        <version>21.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

The system scope is one of solutions, but not in this case. None of my teammates would be happy to download a jar dependency manually.

Building a project including mentioned dependency creates a jar of 515 MBs or 251 MBs without it (system scope).

Comment: Your options are essentially `provided` scope or `runtime` scope if the deprecated `system` scope is not an option. That jar will need to be made available in the classpath of the runtime environment if it is not being packaged.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want the outcome to be? If the dependency isn't bundled in the JAR, and you don't want to make people download it manually, how will it be on the classpath at runtime?

Comment: The idea is to skip one dependency while running "mvn clean install" command. Missing dependency will be provided by the server easily.

Comment: Mark it provided

Comment: Yeah, but then after running mvn clean install I get jar with a capacity of 515 MBs, but I need it way smaller.

Comment: How are you building your jar?

Comment: mvn clean install

Comment: I mean which type of packaging in your pom, and what configuration for any plugins you're using, e.g. the assembly plugin.

Comment: Packaging: jar, additional plugin: spring-boot-maven-plugin

Comment: Just use the maven-war-plugin, the spring-boot-maven-plugin includes provided dependencies in the war it produces.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [tgdavies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11002/tgdavies) for a hint with plugin. The thing that helped me was adding excludeGroupIds like below:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>SECRET</mainClass>
                <excludeGroupIds>com.groupdocs</excludeGroupIds>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```